# How to output the values of a batch file for each host in a text file to a separate output

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the following code

```
    set list=%directory%\Computers.txt
    For /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%list%") do (
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims='='" %%A in ('wmic /node:@%list% OS Get csname /value') do SET system=%%A 

    For /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%list%") do Echo Host Name: %%a >> "%directory%\Info\%%a.log"
    )
```

the script will only output the values of the last host in the `Computers.txt` list in all the hosts `%%a.log`

I have also tried

```
    FOR /F "tokens=2 delims='='" %%A in ('wmic /node:@%list% OS Get csname /value') do SET system=%%A 
    
    For /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%list%") do Echo Host Name: %%a >> "%directory%\Info\%%a.log"
```

the output of

```
psexec @C:\Admin\UDB_ALL\Computers.txt systeminfo| findstr /C:"Physical"
```

is

```
Total Physical Memory:     3,071 MB Available Physical Memory: 2,417 MB systeminfo exited on Ayman-VM with error code 0.  
Total Physical Memory:     3,071 MB Available Physical Memory: 2,397 MB systeminfo exited on Ayman-VM-2 with error code 0.  
Total Physical Memory:     3,071 MB Available Physical Memory: 2,434 MB systeminfo exited on Ayman-VM-3 with error code 0
```

how can i output each value for each host i the desired `%%a.log` ?

Comment: The command line in Windows has absolutely nothing to do with "DOS"

Comment: I see you didn't bother to take my advice from your last question.  Again, don't set environmental variables.  Just use the `FOR` variables directly with your `ECHO` commands.  Also I am not sure why you are using `PSEXEC`.  WMIC can accomplish that same logic.  There is no point in the nested `FOR` commands. You have really over complicated this.

Comment: @Squashman
I have tried the `FOR` as you suggested and i got the same output.
I got the `computer1.log computer2.log` files created but the output im getting in both files is the `computer2` specs.
I tried `psexec` to know if it will change anything in the output only, i know that wmic `/node:@%list%` will work

Comment: @Squashman 
`FOR /F "tokens=2 delims='='" %%A in ('wmic /node:@%list% OS Get csname /value') do SET system=%%A`
`For /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%list%") do echo -------------------------------------------- >> "%directory%\Info\%%a.log"`
`For /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%list%") do Echo Host Name: %%a >> "%directory%\Info\%%a.log"`
i have also tried it like this

Comment: @Squashman   when running this command on CMD  `psexec @C:\Admin\UDB_ALL\Computers.txt systeminfo| findstr /C:"Physical"`
  I get the following `Total Physical Memory:     3,071 MB
Available Physical Memory: 2,417 MB
systeminfo exited on Ayman-VM with error code 0.

Total Physical Memory:     3,071 MB
Available Physical Memory: 2,397 MB
systeminfo exited on Ayman-VM-2 with error code 0.

Total Physical Memory:     3,071 MB
Available Physical Memory: 2,434 MB
systeminfo exited on Ayman-VM-3 with error code 0.`

how can i output each value to the desired `%%a.log` ?

Comment: You shouldn't need the third party utility `PSExec`, or a `For` loop: `@%SystemRoot\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe /Node:@C:\Somewhere\Computers.txt /FailFast:1000 /Output:AllNames.csv OS Get CSName /Format:CSV`. If you're not really looking for the CSName only, which is very likely bacause it will probably be the same as the name already in `Computers.txt`, and you're trying to get more information, like an inventory of PC information, then the question has been covered before. My advice is to use PowerShell, or VBScript/JScript instead, _which are built in and much better for this type of task_.

Comment: @Ayman putting that much code and output into a comment is basically unreadable.  Any addtional information like that should be put in your question by using the [edit] link.

Comment: @Compo , thanks for the reply, the problem is that it has to be a batch only file because it's for an organization that doesn't allow PowerShell and that's why i'm limited with options 
and with your solution i cannot set free disk space value to GB

Comment: My comment uses the same command as yours, `WMIC`, so yours code also provides the result in bytes, not GB. BTW, batch files are not capable of working directly with the number of bytes equivalent of around 2GB or more, so what you'd need to do is search this site for a workaround to split the bytes into workable chunks, make the conversions and then rejoin as necessary, _(if you're not able to use the other built-in scripting tools, VBScript, JScript, or PowerShell)_. I would also strongly advise againt using the very very slow `systeminfo.exe` utility, unless it becomes a very last resort.

Comment: @Compo , thanks a lot for the help, i have confirmed it is possible to use PowerShell in the organization since it will only be used on the Server